# Filter on child collection using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have these two models (a many to many relationship):

```
public class Product
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    #region Navigation properties 
    public List<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    #endregion
}

public class Category
{
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    #region Navigation properties
    public List<Product> Products { get; set; }
    #endregion
}
```

Then I have this action method:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> FilterProducts(List<int> categoryIds)
{
    var productsViewModel = new ProductsViewModel();

    if (categoryIds != null)
    {
        var products = await db.Products
                   .AsNoTracking()
                   .Where(??????????????????????)
                   .Where(p => p.Visible == true)
                   .OrderBy(p => p.Importance)
                   .ToListAsync();

        productsViewModel.Products = products;
    }
    else { // Do something else }

    return PartialView("_ProductsPartial", productsViewModel);
}
```

What I would like to do is to get all the products by `categoryIds` using LINQ (the `.Where(??????)`). So each product has a list of categories. I want to get only the products that contain those `categoryIds`.

Not really sure how construct the LINQ query since the filtering is done on the child collection. Any ideas?

Comment: So you need to get products which categories are the same? or which have at least one category from categoryIds ?

Comment: At least one category.

Comment: I would take the other route and get the products for the specified categories. In other words, query the categories along with their products.

Comment: Actually I think I will need both cases. At least one category. And products that have ALL categories.

Answer (score 1):

This will return you all `Products` which have at least one category from `categoryIds`

```
.Where(x => x.Categories.Any(y => categoryIds.Contains(y.CategoryId)));
```

Answer (score 0):

This will return the products that have **all** categoryIds

```
Where(p => categoryIds.
         Intersect(p.Categories.Select(ctgry => ctgry.CategoryId)).
         Count() == categoryIds.Count())
```

(assuming categoryIds has unique elements and the  elements of List Categories have unique CategoryId fields )

Comment: I'm not understanding the .Count() == categoryIds.Count()? What is it for in this case?

Comment: The 'intersect' part finds the category id's of a given Product that are found in categoryIds also. Then if the number of these ( .Count() ) equals to the size of categoryIds ( categoryIds.Count() ), we know that all items in categoryIds were found in the given Product.